# adsense and proxy servers

Tags: google-adsense

If i surf a site using proxy server then can it increase adsense value or daily hits?

**Edit**

What if some user visit some site and keep hitting the ads. I'm considering that the user is not site owner or having any relevance to the site owner but may want to raise a fake alarm so that ads provider blocks the adesnse account. (Though it is a rare case)

Comment: If you are talking about your own site this is cheating. And I am pretty sure that Google will detect this.

Comment: it is not in my site concern, because anyone can use proxy to visit my site. even i used to do it when i became the victim of domain cache. it is in the concern that can anyone harm my site, hits and adsense  using proxy.

Answer (score 2):

> You shall not, and shall not authorize
>   or encourage any third party to: (i)
>   directly or indirectly generate
>   queries, Referral Events, or
>   impressions of or clicks on any Ad,
>   Link, Search Result, or Referral
>   Button  (including without limitation
>   by clicking on “play” for any video
>   Ad) through any automated, deceptive,
>   fraudulent or other invalid means,
>   including but not limited to through
>   repeated manual clicks, the use of
>   robots or other automated query tools
>   and/or computer generated search
>   requests, and/or the unauthorized use
>   of other search engine optimization
>   services and/or software ...

[AdSense Terms and Conditions](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms)

If Google notes a suspicious pattern of activity on your AdSense account (i.e. all of the referrals are coming from proxy users) I suspect you won't have an AdSense account for very long - "cheating", as such, is ultimately counter-productive.

Comment: Visiting a site doesnt have the intention to increase adsense value or hits for your personal profit, it might be because because i want to decrease this value or hits of others site. Or might be my country doesnt allow me to open that site. Or might be i am the victim of domain cache.

Comment: @articlestack - "If i surf a site using proxy server then can it increase adsense value or daily hits?" Perhaps I am reading that question incorrectly, but it looked like you were asking if you could either (a) click your own AdSense links to make money and/or (b) attempt to game the number of impressions AdSense registers for your site by visiting your own site.

Comment: you are correct @danlefree. But in addition, i was intersted to know harms of this if i do. And action that i can take if someone else do it knowingly. And adsense provider block my site in that case

Comment: "action that i can take if someone else do it knowingly" - It's very unlikely that you'll need to worry about someone else running up clicks on your AdSense account - you and Google are the only two parties who really stand to gain from that, but you're welcome to let Google know if you think it's happening just to cover your bases.